# Gawk [ Print Line After A Matching /word/ ( not using getline )

Tags: regex, gawk

I am new to gawk, I am trying to make a translator using .po file.

This is the example of what is inside .po file

> : quota_by_role.module:73
>
> msgid "Quota deleted."
>
> msgstr "Quota removida."

I came up with this. It basically prints the next line of the line that got a matching word.

```
awk -F'"' 'match($2, /^word_to_translate$/) {printf "%s", $2": ";getline; print $2}' translator.po translator2.po
```

the result will be

```
word_to_translate : something_in_other_language.
```

It works fine, but I want to know if there is an alternative way of doing this without using "Getline".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F'"' '{ if (found){print;exit} }
           $2 ~ /word-to-translate/{ found=1 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
 grep -A1 "matching-word"  filename |grep -v "matching-word"
```

will print the next line of the line that has a "matching-word".